# Lex program to count number of Vowels and Consonants doesnot to terminate even after end of input

Tags: lex

I have written a simple program to count number of vowels and consonants in LEX. But the program does not terminate after I enter input and enters an infinite loop. Here's the program

```
%{
    #include<stdio.h>
    int vow_count = 0;
    int const_count = 0;
%}

%%
[aeiouAEIOU] {vow_count++;}
[a-zA-Z] {const_count++;}
%%

int yywrap(){return 1;}

int main()
{

    printf("Enter a string : ");

    yylex();

    printf("\n No. of vowels = %d", vow_count);
    printf("\n No. of consonants = %d\n", const_count);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output

[image: Output Image]

I have tried almost everything, I have tried with "%option noyywrap", without the yywrap() function.

Also the the program works fine when I take input from a file.

Comment: Have you tried typing control-D, which is what you do on Linux to indicate end-of-file?

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working now. So silly of me

Answer (score 1):

Use getch(); after the last printf statement in the main function. Also, after giving your input in the command prompt, press Ctrl+Z. I'm using Windows, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> to terminate.

After pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> you will get the below output.

[image]